# Add folder in Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to add Folder in my amazon s3 bucket using coding.
Can you please suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 48):

There are no folders in Amazon S3. It just that most of the S3 browser tools available show part of the key name separated by slash as a folder.

If you really need that you can create an empty object with the slash at the end. e.g. "folder/" It will looks like a folder if you open it with a GUI tool and AWS Console.

Comment: It looks like there folders to me?

Answer (score 26):

As everyone has told you, in AWS S3 there aren't any "folders", you're thinking of them incorrectly.  AWS S3 has "objects", these objects can look like folders but they aren't really folders in the fullest sense of the word.  If you look for creating folders on the Amazon AWS S3 you won't find a lot of good results.

There is a way to create "folders" in the sense that you can create a simulated folder structure on the S3, but again, wrap your head around the fact that you are creating objects in S3, not folders.  Going along with that, you will need the command "put-object" to create this simulated folder structure.  Now, in order to use this command, you need the AWS CLI tools installed, go here [AWS CLI Installation](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for instructions to get them installed.

The command is this:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket your-bucket-name --key path/to/file/yourfile.txt --body yourfile.txt
```

Now, the fun part about this command is, you do not need to have all of the "folders" (objects) created before you run this command.  What this means is you can have a "folder" (object) to contain things, but then you can use this command to create the simulated folder structure within that "folder" (object) as I discussed earlier.  For example, I have a "folder" (object) named "importer" within my S3 bucket, lets say I want to insert sample.txt within a "folder" (object) structure of the year, month, and then a sample "folder" (object) within all of that.

If I only have the "importer" object within my bucket, I do not need to go in beforehand to create the year, month, and sample objects ("folders") before running this command.  I can run this command like so:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket-here --key importer/2016/01/sample/sample.txt --body sample.txt
```

The put-object command will then go in and create the path that I have specified in the --key flag.  Here's a bit of a jewel: even if you don't have a file to upload to the S3, you can still create objects ("folders") within the S3 bucket, for example, I created a shell script to "create folders" within the bucket, by leaving off the --body flag, and not specifying a file name, and leaving a slash at the end of the path provided in the --key flag, the system creates the desired simulated folder structure within the S3 bucket without inserting a file in the process.

Hopefully this helps you understand the system a little better.

Note: once you have a "folder" structure created, you can use the S3's "sync" command to syncronize the descendant "folder" with a folder on your local machine, or even with another S3 bucket.

Comment: I realize this question has been dead a while, but I never found a satisfactory answer to this very question myself, I just happened to come across the right terminology and I played with some shell scripts to the point where I figured out how to do this.  So I wanted to give this a real answer for anyone who needs to know how to do this.

Comment: related (for those wondering about the various s3 cli available, e.g,.`s3` vs `s3api` ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396150/127971  Using `aws s3` may be easier though to install and use for many tasks, e.g., to copy all files in local pwd to remote: `aws s3 sync .  s3://my-bucket `

Comment: CLI example of adding the trailing slash, and leaving off the body: `aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key folder/`

Answer (score 18):

Java with AWS SDK:

1. There are no folders in s3, only key/value pairs.  The key can contain slashes (`/`) and that will make it appear as a folder in management console, but programmatically it's not a folder it is a String value.
2. If you are trying to structure your s3 bucket, then your naming conventions (the keys you give your files) can simply follow normal directory patterns, i.e. `folder/subfolder/file.txt`.

   When searching (depending on language you are using), you can search via prefix with a delimiter.  In Java, it would be a `listObjects(String storageBucket, String prefix, String delimiter)` method call.

   The `storageBucket` is the name of your bucket, the `prefix` is the key you want to search, and the `delimiter` is used to filter your search based off the `prefix`.

Answer (score 10):

The [AWS:S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) rails gem does this by itself:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("teaser/images/troll.png", file, AWS_BUCKET)
```

Will automatically create the `teaser` and `images` "folders" if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 6):

With AWS SDK .Net works perfectly, just add "/" at the end of the name folder:

```
var folderKey =  folderName + "/"; //end the folder name with "/"
AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey);
var request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.WithBucketName(AWSBucket);
request.WithKey(folderKey);
request.WithContentBody(string.Empty);
S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
```

Then refresh your AWS console, and you will see the folder

Answer (score 3):

With [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), it is possible to copy an entire folder to a bucket.

```
aws s3 cp /path/to/folder s3://bucket/path/to/folder --recursive
```

There is also the option to **sync** a folder using `aws s3 sync`

Comment: For me the key was putting the folder name into the destination as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is a divisive topic, so here is a screenshot in 2019 of the AWS S3 console for adding *folders* and the note:

> When you create a folder, S3 console creates an object with the above
>   name appended by suffix "/" and that object is displayed as a folder
>   in the S3 console.

Then 'using coding' you can simply adjust the object name by prepending a valid *folder name* string and a forward slash.

[image: Adding folders to S3]

Answer (score 2):

For Swift I created a method where you pass in a `String` for the folder name.

**Swift 3:**

```
import AWSS3

func createFolderWith(Name: String!) {
    let folderRequest: AWSS3PutObjectRequest = AWSS3PutObjectRequest()
    folderRequest.key = Name + "/"
    folderRequest.bucket = bucket
    AWSS3.default().putObject(folderRequest).continue({ (task) -> Any? in
        if task.error != nil {
            assertionFailure("* * * error: \(task.error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("created \(Name) folder")
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Then just call

```
 createFolderWith(Name:"newFolder")
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS (Objective-C), I did following way

You can add below code to create a folder inside amazon s3 bucket programmatically. This is working code snippet. Any suggestion Welcome.

```
-(void)createFolder{
    AWSS3PutObjectRequest *awsS3PutObjectRequest = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];
    awsS3PutObjectRequest.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", @"FolderName"];
    awsS3PutObjectRequest.bucket = @"Bucket_Name";
    AWSS3 *awsS3 = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
    [awsS3 putObject:awsS3PutObjectRequest completionHandler:^(AWSS3PutObjectOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error Creating folder");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Folder Creating Sucessful");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Some explanation in addition to the code would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve what you're looking for (from code/cli):

```
--create/select the file (locally) which you want to move to the folder:

~/Desktop> touch file_to_move

--move the file to s3 folder by executing:

~/Desktop> aws s3 cp file_to_move s3://<path_to_your_bucket>/<new_folder_name>/
```

A new folder will be created on your s3 bucket and you'll now be able to execute cp, mv, rm ... statements i.e. manage the *folder* as usual.

If this new file created above is not required, simply delete it. You now have an s3 bucket created.

Answer (score 0):

You can select language of your choice from available [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)

Alternatively you can try minio client libraries available in [Python](https://github.com/minio/minio-py), [Go](https://github.com/minio/minio-go), [.Net](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet), [Java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java), [Javascript](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) for your application development environment, it has example directory with all basic operations listed.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)

Comment: sadly, your examples don't include an example of creating a folder as part of putting an object...

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.2 you can create folder using

```
func createFolderWith(Name: String!) {
    let folderRequest: AWSS3PutObjectRequest = AWSS3PutObjectRequest()
    folderRequest.key = Name + "/"
    folderRequest.bucket = "Your Bucket Name"
    AWSS3.defaultS3().putObject(folderRequest).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if task.error != nil {
            assertionFailure("* * * error: \(task.error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("created \(Name) folder")
        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below creates a empty directory called "mydir1".

Below is nodejs code, it should be similar for other languages.

The trick is to have slash (/) at the end of the name of object, as in "mydir1/", otherwise a file with name "mydir1" will be created.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '\\my-aws-config.json');
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
    Bucket: "mybucket1",
    Key: "mydir1/",
    ServerSideEncryption: "AES256" };

s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(data);           // successful response
        return;
        /*
         data = {
         ETag: "\"6805f2cfc46c0f04559748bb039d69ae\"",
         ServerSideEncryption: "AES256",
         VersionId: "Ri.vC6qVlA4dEnjgRV4ZHsHoFIjqEMNt"
         }
         */
    } });
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Answer (score 0):

in-order to create a directory inside s3 bucket and copy contents inside that is pretty simple.

S3 command can be used: 
aws s3 cp abc/def.txt  s3://mybucket/abc/

Note: / is must that makes the directory, otherwise it will become a file in s3.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query is just simply creating a folder inside folder(subfolder).
so while coping any directory data inside a bucket sub folder use command like this.

aws s3 cp mudit s3://mudit-bucket/Projects-folder/mudit-subfolder --recursive

It will create a subfolder and put ur directory contents in it. Also once your subfolder data gets empty. Your Subfolder will automatically gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy command to create a folder while copy a file.

```
aws s3 cp test.xml s3://mybucket/myfolder/test.xml
```